# How do I move downloaded files into a specified download folder? Python web scraper

Tags: python, json, for-loop, web-scraping, python-requests

I am building a web scraping application. Here is where I am with it:

```
import requests
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd


url = "https://xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=emberiza+pusilla+type:song"
data = requests.get(url).json()
species_name = 'emberiza_pusilla'


df = pd.DataFrame(data['recordings'])


os.mkdir(f'/Users/warren/Downloads/{species_name}+xeno+canto+scraped+recordings')


filtered_df = df.drop(['gen',
                       'sp',
                       'en',
                       'ssp',
                       'group',
                       'alt',
                       'rec',
                       'sex',
                       'stage',
                       'url',
                       'sono',
                       'osci',
                       'uploaded',
                       'also',
                       'temp',
                       'regnr',
                       'auto',
                       'dvc',
                       'mic',
                       'smp'],
                    axis = 1)

for file in filtered_df['file']:
    print(f"Downloading file: {file}")
    download = requests.get(file)
    shutil.move(download, f'/Users/warren/Downloads/{species_name}+xeno+canto+scraped+recordings')
```

The for loop above, however, does not work. It spits back a type error. The aim of the code was to move the downloaded file into the specified path, but it doesn't work. Essentially, what I am aiming to do is scrape .wav files from a sound archive, and then store them into an individual folder that is created upon starting the programme. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a dataframe?

Comment: requests.get is not creating a file, it will return a Response object from which you can check returned data and dump it somewhere else. That's why your shutil.move is breaking. | Also, please always include error. "It spits back a type error" - that type error actually says it expects a string/path-like and got Response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than downloading then moving the file, why not stream directly to the desired location?

I see no value in using a dataframe for this.

I do see value in multithreading.

I have determined empirically that the website can become overwhelmed with download requests hence the rather dubious-looking sleep

```
from requests import Session as SESSION
from os import makedirs as MAKEDIRS
from os.path import join as JOIN
import http
from time import sleep as SLEEP
from sys import stderr as STDERR
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as TPE

URL = 'https://xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings'
TARGETDIR = '/Volumes/G-Drive/recordings'
CHUNK = 16 * 1024
RETRIABLE = {
    http.HTTPStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
    http.HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    http.HTTPStatus.BAD_GATEWAY,
    http.HTTPStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
    }
MAXRETRIES = 10
HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_4_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.5 Safari/605.1.15'
    }

def download(t):
    url, target = t
    retries = 0
    with SESSION() as session:
        while True:
            with session.get(url, stream=True, headers=HEADERS) as response:
                if response.status_code in RETRIABLE:
                    if (retries := retries + 1) > MAXRETRIES:
                        print(f'Failed to process {url}. Too many retries', file=STDERR)
                        break
                    SLEEP(1)
                else:
                    response.raise_for_status()
                    with open(JOIN(TARGETDIR, target), 'wb') as output:
                        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK):
                            output.write(chunk)
                    break

def main():
    MAKEDIRS(TARGETDIR, exist_ok=True)
    params = {
        'query': 'emberiza pusilla type:song'
    }
    with SESSION() as session:
        with session.get(URL, params=params, headers=HEADERS) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            args = [(r['file'], r['file-name']) for r in response.json()['recordings']]
            with TPE() as tpe:
                tpe.map(download, args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a new file with `open()` where you specify full path, for example:

```py
import os
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=emberiza+pusilla+type:song"
data = requests.get(url).json()
species_name = "emberiza_pusilla"


df = pd.DataFrame(data["recordings"])


directory_name = f"/Users/warren/Downloads/{species_name}+xeno+canto+scraped+recordings"
os.mkdir(directory_name)

filtered_df = df.drop(
    [
        "gen",
        "sp",
        "en",
        "ssp",
        "group",
        "alt",
        "rec",
        "sex",
        "stage",
        "url",
        "sono",
        "osci",
        "uploaded",
        "also",
        "temp",
        "regnr",
        "auto",
        "dvc",
        "mic",
        "smp",
    ],
    axis=1,
)

for i, file in enumerate(filtered_df["file"], 1):
    print(f"Downloading file: {file}")
    file_name = f'{directory_name}/{i}.wav'

    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f_out:
        download = requests.get(file)
        f_out.write(download.content)
```